# Does this statement generalize to inductive inference?

Tags: probability, first-order-logic

The following statement is true for deductive logic (e.g. in a boolean algebra):
$$a\wedge b \Rightarrow \neg c \quad \text{if and only if }\quad a \Rightarrow \neg(b\wedge c).$$

It seems like you can transform deductive inference into inductive inference by replacing implication $(a\Rightarrow b)$ with plausibility $(a|b)$, so my question is whether a similar statement holds in probability theory, i.e. is it true in general that

$$p(AB|\bar C) = p(A|\overline{BC})$$

provided $p(\bar C) \neq 0$ and $p(\overline{BC})\neq 0$?

I'm unfamiliar with axiomatic probability theory, so I'm not sure how to approach such a statement from first principles (rather than just making algebraic manipulations I've been taught are valid.)

Comment: Can you explain (either directly or by linking to some paper or citing a book) what you mean by "plausibility" here? The notation $p(A|B)$ is usually reserved for [conditional probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Definition).

Comment: Yes, in _Probability Theory: The Logic of Science_, Jaynes derives the axioms of probability from some commonsense constraints on what kinds of inferences you can make. He uses "plausibility" to refer to the algebraic structure that conforms to these constraints, before ultimately picking the unit interval [0,1] of probabilities in particular. It would be okay to substitute probability wherever plausibility occurs, since probabilities are a special case.